# Installing Geopandas from within ArcGIS Pro tool script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geopandas, installation

I'm creating a script to analyse landcover within an AOI which I'll turn into a geoprocessing tool. I want to use the ESA 2022 landcover and download from within the tool using the code provided on the ESA data access page.

I'm aware I need to install geopandas into the conda environment most recommendations seem to suggest doing this in the Python Command Prompt. However, eventually, this tool needs to stand alone and be used by non-techincal staff to carry out the landcover analysis, i.e. just run from the geoprocessing pane.

Is there a way I can include the installation of geopandas to allow me to download relevant landcover data WITHIN the script for the geoprocessing tool I'm creating so no additional steps are required from those using the tool?

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: Yes, post the code or at least the link to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply - the answer is probably NO. If your dependency (`geopandas`) was small, you might be able to simply include a couple extra Python files with your tool. To my knowledge, this is a larger package, and best *installed* via supported ways (conda, pip, etc), meaning it should be installed and ready within the Python environment on the machine of the person running the tool, NOT included with the tool itself.

Personally, I'd do an import check for the module, and if NOT available, print out some basic instructions on how to install/get the package.